# Structured bindings on a map of string to string not working

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, structured-bindings

This is my code:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> map = {{"a","b"},{"c","d"}};
for(auto& [key,value] : map) {
    key = std::string("c");
    value = std::string("c");
}
```

and when i compile it i get

```
error: no viable overloaded '='
```

what i'm doing wrong? Shouldn't `key` and `value` be reference to `string`?

Comment: The variable `key` is actually of type `const std::string &` here.  Hence the error when you try to assign to it.

Comment: @G.M. can you please tell me why it is const? i can see it from the debugger, but i don't understand why

Comment: If you could change the value of a map's key in place, you'd break the sorting of the map.

Comment: thank you @1201ProgramAlarm , if you want, make it an answer and i'll mark as correct!

Comment: thank you @G.M. , if you want, make it an answer and i'll mark as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key value in a `std::map` is a constant.  Since the sort order of the map depends on the value of the key, if you change the key you'll probably break that ordering and have a node in the wrong place.

In your code, `key` will be a `const string &`, while `value` will be a `string &` (so you can change the value).

If you need to change the key for an entry in a map, you need to extract the value from the map, erase the original value, then re-insert the value using the new key.